# Change table row color when radio button in td is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

Ok guys, I have something really challenging for you today.

I have a table which has two cells. In the second cell of every row, I have a radio button. I want to be able to change the color of the row whenever the radio button is clicked.

To do that I pass the argument `this` to the function that will do the work. I expect `this` to be the radio button that was clicked. Then I find the `tr` of that button and change its color with  `$changed_tr.css("bgcolor", "72ff76");` but that doesn't work.
What am I missing out here?

```js
function save(avail_id, map_id, radio) {
    //some api call...
    // change background color
    var $changed_tr = $(radio).closest('td').closest('tr');
    $changed_tr.css("bgcolor", "72ff76");        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header-text">
    <p>
    <table border=1>
        <tr>
            <td>yyy
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-11"
                    onclick="save(105146,-11,this);">
                </label>Discontinued
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-8"
                    onclick="save(105146,-8,this);">
                </label>Future product
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-6"
                    onclick="save(105146,-6,this);">
                </label>In store only
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-5"
                    onclick="save(105146,-5,this);">
                </label>In Stock
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-4"
                    checked
                    onclick="save(105146,-4,this);">
                </label>Delayed delivery
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-2"
                    onclick="save(105146,-2,this);">
                </label>Out of stock
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-1"
                    onclick="save(105146,-1,this);">
                </label>Unknown
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr
            >
            <td>
                xxx
            </td>
            <td>
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-11"
                    onclick="save(105521,-11,this);">
                </label>Discontinued
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-8"
                    onclick="save(105521,-8,this);">
                </label>Future product
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-6"
                    checked
                    onclick="save(105521,-6,this);">
                </label>In store only
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-5"
                    onclick="save(105521,-5,this);">
                </label>In Stock
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-4"
                    onclick="save(105521,-4,this);">
                </label>Delayed delivery
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-2"
                    onclick="save(105521,-2,this);">
                </label>Out of stock
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-1"
                    onclick="save(105521,-1,this);">
                </label>Unknown
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </p>
</div>
<p>
</p>
<script>
    function save(avail_id, map_id, radio) {
      //some api call...
        // change background color
         var $changed_tr = $(radio).closest('td').closest('tr');
        $changed_tr.css("bgcolor", "72ff76");

    }
</script>
```

Comment: `bgcolor` is not valid css... don't forget about the # infront of the color code. 
[ _Nevermind, see @Rory McCrossan answer_ ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is because the CSS property name is `background-color`, not `bgcolor`. The hex colour value should also have a `#` prefix, like this:

```
$changed_tr.css("background-color", "#72ff76");
```

Also note that your HTML is invalid as `p` element cannot contain a `table`. You can also place the text within the `label` element to expand the hit area for the checkboxes. I'd also suggest you amend your code to use unobtrusive event handlers instead of the outdated `onclick` event attributes, something like this:

```js
$('table input').change(function() {
  //some api call...
  
  var $changed_tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  $changed_tr.css("background-color", "#72ff76");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td>yyy
    </td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-11" data-availid="105146" />
        Discontinued
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-8" data-availid="105146" />
        Future product
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-6" data-availid="105146" />
        In store only
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-5" data-availid="105146" />
        In Stock
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-4" checked data-availid="105146" />
        Delayed delivery
      </label>

      <label>
       <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-2" data-availid="105146" />
        Out of stock
      </label>

      <label>
       <input type="radio" name="target_105146" value="-1" data-availid="105146" />
        Unknown
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>xxx</td>
    <td>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-11" data-availid="105521" />
        Discontinued
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-8" data-availid="105521" />
        Future product
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-6" checked data-availid="105521">
        In store only
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-5" data-availid="105521" />
       In Stock
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-4" data-availid="105521" />
        Delayed delivery
      </label>

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-2" data-availid="105521" />
      </label>
      Out of stock

      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="target_105521" value="-1" data-availid="105521" />
        Unknown
      </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, bgcolor is not a valid CSS property, but 'background-color' is. Hyphenated CSS properties are accessible through the camel-cased variant. This means that "background-color", becomes accessible as "backgroundColor".

TLDR: `$changed_tr.css('backgroundColor', 'red')`

Answer (score 0):

```
function save(avail_id, map_id, radio) {
       //some api call...
       // change background color
       var $changed_tr = $(radio).parents('tr'); // tr is ancestor 
       $changed_tr.css("background", "red"); 
 }
```

Change the code to this. Use 'background' attribute and color is not in correct format.